# Python Selenium Local Storage returns None

Tags: python, django, selenium, phantomjs

i am writing some unit tests with Django and Selenium with PhantomJS.

Things seem to be working, apart from the fact i need to access the browser local storage to validate that my tokens are correct.

My code so far is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver import WebDriver
class UserSeleniumTestCase(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(UserSeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(10)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(UserSeleniumTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()

    def setUp(self):
        # create the users.


    def test_login(self):
        self.selenium.get(
            '%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, reverse_lazy('account_login')))
        self.assertIn(_('Sign In'), self.selenium.title)

        login_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("login")
        login_input.send_keys('test@example.com')
        password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.send_keys('safe!')
        self.selenium.find_element_by_id("btn_login").click()

        self.selenium.get(
            '%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, reverse_lazy('polls:poll-add')))

        self.assertIn(_('Create Polls'), self.selenium.title)

        print(self.selenium.execute_script('localStorage.getItem("token");'))
```

My problem is that i am getting `None` with `print(self.selenium.execute_script('localStorage.getItem("token");'))` were at this point in the login it should be populated (in the browser works just fine). Am i missing something? i also tried `print(self.selenium.execute_script('window.localStorage.getItem("token");'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to *return from the JS script* in order to see the value at the Python level:

```
print(self.selenium.execute_script('return localStorage.getItem("token");'))
```